# Remove item from RecyclerView from fragment

Tags: android

So I have the view that represents a single row in the RecyclerView and each row has a delete button.

**ItemSummaryView**

```
public class ItemSummaryView extends RelativeLayout {
 ....
   public void setOnItemClickListener(MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
       this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
 ....
   deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> onItemClickListener.onDeleteClick());
}
```

In my adapter I use ItemSummaryView as part of my view holder

**MyAdapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       return new ItemViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false));
      }
      return null;
  }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) 
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).bind(itemsList.get(position), itemsList.size() > 1);
      }
  }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onDeleteClick();
    }

 private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final String ITEM = "item";
    private ItemSummaryView view;

    private ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = (ItemSummaryView) itemView;
        view.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }

    private void bind() {
        view.setContentDescription(ITEM + getAdapterPosition());
    }
  }
}
```

And than on my fragment I want to implement the delete method

**MyFragment**

```
public class MyFragment implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener  {

      @Override
      public void onDeleteClick() {
        //add logic here to delete row
      }
}
```

My question is how do I get the position of the row when clicking the delete button from the fragment so that I can delete it.(implementing the click in the adapter is not an option).

Comment: Do you have screenshots as an example? It's very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here and why you need to use the Fragment. and why you can't use the click in an adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

     private OnItemClickListener listener;
     .
     .
     .
     public void setListener(OnItemClickListener listener){

        this.listener = listener;
     }

     @Override
     public void onDeleteClick() {

        listener.onDeleteClick();
     }
```

MyFragment

```
adapter.setListener(this);
```

Hopes this helps.